# how to position the angular MaterIal modal?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to open a modal.

I have a table in detalis-component

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Manager:</td>
        <td>EmployeeManger</td>
        <td><app-report-to></app-report-to></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in the component "app-report-to"
I write the function that open the modal :

```js
 openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ReportPopUpComponent,{
      width: '50px', height: '50px',
      data:{
        message: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
        buttonText: {
          ok: 'Save',
          cancel: 'No'
        }
      }
    });
    

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
     
    });
  }
```

in report.html

```html
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Open Confirm Dialog</button>
```

but the modal opens on the left side-down.
some suggestion?
thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO community, @Sharon! I guessed you use the modal component from the Angular material library and used my courage to update the question accordingly. Please feel free to update the question if I misunderstand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "position" parameter along with your "data" parameter as described in https://v5.material.angular.io/components/dialog/api